# Indy TIdHTTPResponseInfo.ContentType not being set

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

I have written a TIdHTTPServer web server.  Indy version is 10, Delphi is 2007.

I use the following code to send back jpeg, gif, png, etc, files:

```
      AResponseInfo.ServeFile(AContext,rootpath+ARequestInfo.document);
      AResponseInfo.ContentType := 'image/jpeg';
      AResponseInfo.ContentType := GetMimeTypeFromFile('.'+ExtractFileDir(rootpath+ARequestInfo.document));
```

The images display properly in all browsers.  But I see (via console in Chrome) they are being returned as MIME type: text/html.
I have tried both **image/jpeg** and the **GetMIMTypeFromFile** methods and both yield text/html.

Is there another call I have to make?  I saw in other threads calls to the **AResponseInfo.WriteHeader** function.  But when added it raises an exception the header is being written twice.

Answer (score 3):

Actually found the problem.  Need to specify the Content Type **BEFORE** the ServeFile call.

```
  AResponseInfo.ContentType := 'image/jpeg';
  AResponseInfo.ServeFile(AContext,rootpath+ARequestInfo.document);
```